# Grammar of elimination reactions

Tags: terminology, elimination

I would like to double check the English grammar of a sentence of an elimination reaction, but I cannot find an answer.

I'd normally say "the elimination of A with X as the leaving group", where A is the initial compound.

So my question is saying "the elimination of X from A", correct? I've never been told not to, but I *feel* it is wrong chemically, so I would change it to "the leaving/loss of X from A", which unfortunately sounds casual.

EDIT.
So based on the answer below I was totally wrong —I am glad I asked!— and to recap with A as reactant and X as leaving group and optional parts in parenthesis:

- ✓ → ✗ — the elimination of A (with loss of X)
- ✗ — the elimination of X (from A)
- ✓ — the loss of X (from A)
- ✓ → iffy — the leaving of X (from A)
- ✓ → ✗  — A gets/is eliminated
- ✗ — X gets/is eliminated from A
- ✓ — A undergoes elimination (with loss of X)

Comment: How about "A undergoes elimination under [conditions] by loss of X"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no chemistry behind this question and it is more about grammatical correction. It is better suited in ELU.SE.

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic: chemical terminology is OK. However, I would also not feel comfortable offering a specific suggestion on how to phrase it, unless some more context is added. That said, phrases like "loss of chloride ion" are accurate and widely used.

Comment: I was not sure myself when posting. But I certain the English language stack exchange would say that "the elimination of X (leaving group)" is correct, while from the two comments and my own question the answer seems to be no: the leaving group is lost and the substrate is eliminated, while "the elimination of the leaving group" is wrong by a possibly unspoken convention (62k vs. 100k results in google for "elimination of leaving group" vs. "loss of leaving group").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"A gets eliminated" or "the elimination of A" is just plain wrong, typical sloppy lab slang by many (too often native?) speakers. Very common, but still terrible.

As you say, the small molecule **X** gets eliminated **from** substrate **A**. Chemical English is still just English, and that is the correct way to put the case in question into words in this language.

"**A** undergoes elimination" (short for "**A** undergoes *an* elimination *reaction*) is a widely used, and imo also correct, variant.

Comment: No, being native or not is not very important. It rather (il)logic. A literal translation of the elimination of A would be wrong in French Spanish etc as well. Also "the precipitate is filtered" is plain wrong but accepted. Terrible is also "vacuum evaporation" to mean evaporation in vacuum :) plus one anyway.

Comment: I (OP) may be a native speaker, but have a non-English name, so I thought that was a rather risky statement. :-D

Comment: So to clarify your answer @Karl, you are saying that the associated verb _to eliminate_ should not be used in Chemistry? I thought it was okay, with the caveat that in English _to eliminate_ is transitive ("I eliminate waste"), but in Chemistry I would have said it is intransitive or passive only ("The substrate is/gets eliminated via the loss of leaving group").
My question was specifically about the usage of "the elimination of leaving group" statements, which I believe is wrong (but another author did not).

Comment: @MatteoFerla Why should the correct way to say this in normal English suddenly  be *wrong*. There is no "Chemical" English, only British and American English (and a few more regional, orthograhic variants).

Comment: Sorry, I had not noticed that you had edited to include "elimination of A". Wikipedia uses it extensively though.

Comment: Nitpick: \*that's or \*that is